# Chart disappears after page submit

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex-5.1, anychart

I was trying to build an Oracle Apex 5.1 app with new mobile theme which has a collapsable dynamic content region.
Behind this region there's a pl/sql code that prints out a chart codelet into the HTML body which consists of a "host" div and a JS script block that generates the chart (AnyChart 7.14.4) into it.

Everything works fine on the first page visit but when I press a region button (in an another, static region) which submits the page via dynamic action, the chart's completely gone (although the div stays spanned to its original size).

Do you have any idea what's behind this symptom?

!UPDATE!

This JS function is generated by a page process (Pre-rendering/before regions):

```js
function createChart() {

  anychart.theme("darkEarth");    

  var dataSet = [
["2006.10.17",212.82,22.58,3.10,2.79],
["2006.10.18",212.04,22.57,3.10,2.81],
["2006.10.19",208.46,22.40,3.06,2.78],
["2006.10.20",208.60,22.43,3.06,2.78],
["2006.10.23",210.47,22.56,3.08,2.81],
["2006.10.24",209.18,22.57,3.09,2.80],
["2006.10.25",208.00,22.50,3.08,2.78],
["2006.10.26",205.22,22.35,3.04,2.76],
["2006.10.27",204.89,22.26,3.04,2.76],
["2006.10.30",205.93,22.20,3.05,2.76],
["2006.10.31",204.41,22.00,3.03,2.75],
]; 

  var seriesList = anychart.data.mapAsTable(dataSet);
  
  var chart = anychart.line();
  chart.crosshair().enabled(true).yLabel().enabled(false);
  chart.crosshair().yStroke(null);
  chart.tooltip().positionMode("point");  
  chart.yAxis().title("%");

  var credits = chart.credits();
  credits.enabled(false);

  chart.animation(true);
  chart.title().enabled(false);
  chart.xAxis().labels().padding([5]);

  var series_1 = chart.line(seriesList[0]);
  series_1.name("HUF");
  
  var series_2 = chart.line(seriesList[1]);
  series_2.name("CZK");
  
  var series_3 = chart.line(seriesList[2]);
  series_3.name("PLN");
  
  var series_4 = chart.line(seriesList[3]);
  series_4.name("RON");
  
  for (i = 0; i < chart.getSeriesCount(); i++) 
    {
      chart.getSeriesAt(i).hoverMarkers().enabled(true).type("circle").size(4);
   chart.getSeriesAt(i).tooltip().position("right").anchor("left").offsetX(5).offsetY(5);

    }

  chart.legend().enabled(true).fontSize(13);
  chart.container("chartContainer");
 
  chart.draw();
}
```

This is followed by a static region in position body2 with the following content:

```html
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
        createChart();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: UPDATE: These Anychart libraries are added (as page/theme level setting): anychart.min.js, anychart-ui.min.js, dark_earth.min.js. All anychart JS objects are locally declared in the dynamic script.

Comment: Seems to me it's gonna be more Apex/HTML issue than AnyChart...

Comment: Press F12, go to console, check if is there any error when the chart disappears

Comment: The only warning in Firefox is the following (no errors): "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."

Comment: If is it easy for you, you could try to change how the chart is created.. in the region just put the html chart. Try to put the .js code on a dynamic action to execute on page loading... I don't know why this happen, this is just a sugestion. Just to inform, it seems to me, APEX is no longer using anychart library. In the current version (5.1) and in the later version I think they will use the oracle-jet library. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/5841/index-en.html

Comment: ANOTHER inetersting detail: the content of the chart container div is doubling after each page submit!

Comment: Could you post this pl/sql code that you are using to generate this chart?

Comment: Thank you very much, romeuBraga! Formerly I've tried many ways (dynamic pl/sql regions as well) but always with same results. By the way I go for the Oracle Jet, until then here is a very helpful document if it comes to "native" chart regions and AnyChart JS: https://www.anychart.com/technical-integrations/plugins/oracle-apex/

Answer (score 1):

We are afraid that this issue goes beyond AnyChart area responsibility. Also, we've never met a similar problem. We would recommend you to forward this query to Oracle tech support.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to post a ticket to Oracle and AnyChart support ether (with detailed information)

Answer (score 0):

I did a test page here: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:18

Login on: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550

```
workspace: stackquestions
login: test
pwd: test
app: 145797
page: 18
```

---

In this page I have a process on "Pre-Rendering" > "Before Regions"

```
begin
htp.p(
'<script>
function createChart() {

        anychart.theme("darkEarth");                

        var dataSet = [
["2006.10.17",212.82,22.58,3.10,2.79],
["2006.10.18",212.04,22.57,3.10,2.81],
["2006.10.19",208.46,22.40,3.06,2.78],
["2006.10.20",208.60,22.43,3.06,2.78],
["2006.10.23",210.47,22.56,3.08,2.81],
["2006.10.24",209.18,22.57,3.09,2.80],
["2006.10.25",208.00,22.50,3.08,2.78],
["2006.10.26",205.22,22.35,3.04,2.76],
["2006.10.27",204.89,22.26,3.04,2.76],
["2006.10.30",205.93,22.20,3.05,2.76],
["2006.10.31",204.41,22.00,3.03,2.75],
];  

        var seriesList = anychart.data.mapAsTable(dataSet);

        var chart = anychart.line();
        chart.crosshair().enabled(true).yLabel().enabled(false);
        chart.crosshair().yStroke(null);
        chart.tooltip().positionMode("point");      
        chart.yAxis().title("%");

        var credits = chart.credits();
        credits.enabled(false);

        chart.animation(true);
        chart.title().enabled(false);
        chart.xAxis().labels().padding([5]);

        var series_1 = chart.line(seriesList[0]);
        series_1.name("HUF");

        var series_2 = chart.line(seriesList[1]);
        series_2.name("CZK");

        var series_3 = chart.line(seriesList[2]);
        series_3.name("PLN");

        var series_4 = chart.line(seriesList[3]);
        series_4.name("RON");

        /*for (i = 0; i < chart.getSeriesCount(); i++) 
    {
      chart.getSeriesAt(i).hoverMarkers().enabled(true).type("circle").size(4);
            chart.getSeriesAt(i).tooltip().position("right").anchor("left").offsetX(5).offsetY(5);

    }*/

        chart.legend().enabled(true).fontSize(13);
        chart.container("chartContainer");

        chart.draw();
}</script>'


);
end
```

---

I put the files .js on "HTML Header"

[image]

---

And the HTML on the source of a region

[image]

---

Could you replicate your problem in this page?